# How to create a doted effect over the pic or video?

Tags: after-effects

See this website's background. It's amazing!

http://www.weblitesolucoes.com.br/

How can I create the same effect?

Comment: Which effect ?? the video ? the gray lined overlay ? please can you be more specific, there is nothing overly special on that page which would not be hard at all to reproduce from the video side, the rest would all be web coding via HTML, CSS, etc

Answer (score 1):

This is simply an overlay done in the browser, not a video effect.  You can see the source video [here](http://res.cloudinary.com/contas-vx-weblite/video/upload/v1485796261/F2Conecta/static/uploads/site/video/VideoMP4.mp4).  It simply has a white dot repeated over it in browser using a png that's stored in-line in the CSS.